# How do I resolve "Error reading cpu table" when trying to run "sudo apt update"?

Tags: 21.04

Hello I am using ubuntu 21.04 and everytime I go to do sudo apt update I I get E: Error reading cpu table. I have no idea how to fix this. If anyone can help that would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: It's easiest if you provide a full paste of the command & error message.  A quick scan online and some posts indicate it's an issue with a corrupted *file-system* which is easiest to fix by booting a *live* system (eg. installation media & use "Try Ubuntu"), and file-system check (`fsck`) via command or GUI tool.  Others indicate it's because of an interrupted install and fixes are more varied.

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply. I am a bit confused on what you are saying, probably cause I am new to Ubuntu and new to linux in general. If you can explain it more for a noob like myself that would be great.

Comment: You haven't said if you were using a Ubuntu 21.04 Desktop, or Ubuntu 21.04 Server system, nor provided a full copy/paste of the error message.  I would boot *live* media (eg. Ubuntu installation system & use the "Try Ubuntu" option) and perform *file-system* checks there (GUI or command tools can be used). This isn't Ubuntu/Linux specific detail; *live* media was available with Windows XP thru 10 but is expensive & thus rarely seen (available to OEM/enterprise).  As I cannot see the full command & error message, I'm unwilling to provide specific advice, only generic advice that can do no harm.

Comment: fyi:  `fsck` or the file-system check command is called `chkdsk` in DOS/windows... it doesn't actually check a disk, but checks a file-system for *logical* errors that exists on a disk/partition/storage-device..   It doesn't check for bad sectors/clusters/inodes/blocks, but only file-system *logical* errors such as invalid pointers etc... If you're familiar with `chkdsk` from microsoft products since 1981; it's the same thing.. Microsoft called it `fsck` too before 1981 (ie. on their Xenix products)